# Replace command with its output in /etc/environment

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I have script as

```
   S3_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\`cat /tmp/decrypted | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d, -f1\`
   S3_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\`cat /tmp/decrypted | cut -d= -f3\`
```

I want that whenever i do

```
   source /etc/environment
```

the commands between ` and ` get executed and are replaced by their outputs
so that the resulting /etc/environment looks like this

```
   S3_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SOMEKEY
   S3_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=SOMEID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `/etc/environment` works. It doesn't get evaluated and certainly not by an arbitrary shell.

You can do what you want but you'll need to use a shell startup script instead (and that won't apply to non-shell processes).

But note that unless `/tmp/decrypted` is a short-lived file this isn't really even remotely meaningful "security" (and even if it is, which I don't see how it really could be for this usage, it still isn't really remotely meaningful as a "security" measure).

Comment: Thanks for your reply i thought this might happen, I finally compromised with this 
    echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`cat /tmp/decrypted | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d,     -f1`
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`cat /tmp/decrypted | cut -d= -f3`
    " >> /etc/environment  

so that the /etc/environment file becomes hardcoded so that i can do source it

Comment: Right, just putting the decoded values in there will work and isn't meaningfully less secure in any way I can think of.